# About strong reference cycles for closures in Swift

Tags: ios, swift

I have defined a class called `Person`. This is my code:

```
    class Person { 
        var closure: (() -> ())?
        var name: String

        init(name: String) {

            self.name = name
            print("\(name) is being initialized")
        }

        deinit {
            print("\(name) is being deinitialized")
        }
    }
```

then I use `Person` in class called `ViewController`:

```
class ViewController: UIViewController {

    var person = Person(name: "john")
    let aStr = "john is a cute boy"


    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        person.closure = {
            print("\(self.aStr)")
        }
        person.closure!()
    }
}
```

In my opinion, the picture of memory about my code like this :
[image: memory]

So, from above picture, in my opinion, it will cause strong reference cycle between the three instances, but I can not get any leak from `Instruments`, so I have some confusion.

Does this code cause strong reference cycle?

If not, when will ARC deallocate the instance of `Person`? the method named `deinit` in `Person` class is never called.

Comment: This does have a retain cycle as @Puttin stated, but it isn't a leak.  A leak occurs when an object has a non-zero retain count but there are no references.  Here you have a non-zero retain count but there are still references.  They are circular references, but this doesn't make a leak

Comment: oh, I got it , thank you very much,  but now I have another question, If it doesn't cause memory leak, need I resolve it? Or it will cause leak in other places?

Comment: It causes memory to be "lost" since it will prevent those objects from being deallocated, so yes, you should  avoid it using a weak self. It just isn't something that the leaks instrument can find for you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, this's a typical retain cycle.

To solve this problem use `[weak self]` in your closure

```
person.closure = { [weak self] in
    guard let strongSelf = self else { return }
    print("\(strongSelf.aStr)")
}
```

---

To really create a leak.
I create a demo App. Root is a navController.
The navController has a root controller. Let's call it buttonController.
When you click button in the buttonController, it create your ViewController and push to navController.
When you click back button in navigation bar, the navController pop your ViewController instance.

Profile it, then you will see the leak and the retain cycle in Instruments.

Xcode default template of iOS App use a single page, which always retain your ViewController instance. If the ViewController instance is still used by the system, it's actually not a leak yet.
So push & pop show that leak for you.

Comment: @Paulw11 Really? that '`' is needed.

Comment: How about using a new name like `strongSelf` instead?

Comment: @vacawama yeah, that would be cool. I just used to write this. Updated.

Comment: Why I got no leaks in the **leaks** of **instruments**

Comment: I embed my ViewController in NavigationViewController in storyboard, now the RootViewController of my app is NavigationViewController, not my ViewController,  so Xcode always retain NavigationViewController instance? I understand right? But when I push to NextViewController, I still got no leaks in instruments. Forgive me if I wasted you time. I don't know how to @ you, Puttin.

Comment: @XiaoMZhang because although the window.rootVC is your navVC. Your navVC retain your ViewController instance. Even if you push your NextViewController instance, the ViewController instance is still in the navVC's `viewControllers`

Comment: @XiaoMZhang the easy way to get the leak is like what I did. Push & Pop the ViewController several times.

Comment: @Puttin Yes, the way works, I got any leaks and I have learnt a lot, thank you very much! good luck for you!